# How to get response using WebClient in powershell

Tags: powershell, web-client

I saw the following code in stackoverflow :

```
$uri = "http://google.com"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$json = $wc.DownloadString($uri)
```

And it is working fine , but what I am wandering for, is that somehow I could store the status code of the URL I am hitting.

Actually when I am hitting a URL having status 404 , it is returning a exception for same.

Can anyone help me regarding how I can store the status or even if I can store the exception it is returning back.

Comment: You're looking for `WebRequest` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: Actually for both, but my main issue is status, I need status of the URL stored in some variable

Comment: You can see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191812/how-to-run-a-web-request-using-default-credentials-in-powershell I just want to fetch the status of some URLs using my default credentials

Answer (score 2):

This should be a good starting point for you:

```
#requires -Version 3

$out = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://google.com' -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable 'conn'
```

Then you can check `$conn` for connection details.  `$out` will have the status, returns, etc.  `$out.StatusCode = 200` in this example.

Comment: Thanks for help, but actually I am working on version 2.0 of powershell, but even though it gave me some idea , thanks once again I will work on it

Comment: if any help you can provide me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191812/how-to-run-a-web-request-using-default-credentials-in-powershell on this it will be great too

Answer (score 1):

I did some study and saw that the following method is working fine in powershell 2.0

```
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$req.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
try
{
$res = $req.GetResponse()
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
$res = $_.Exception.Response
}
$int = [int]$res.StatusCode
echo $int
```

And this worked perfectly as per my requirement.