# How to run a web request using default credentials in Powershell

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest

I am working on the following code.

```
$HTTP_Request =[System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
echo $HTTP_Status
```

But I want to run it using my default credentials, because there are few URLs which returns 401 ,that is client not authorized and for that I need it to run using my default credentials.

Can anyone help me regarding same, as I want to store the status of some URLs and  this code is working fine except for those which are protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was to run web request while using default credentials, here are the solutions I found:

for powershell 2.0:-

```
 $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
 $req.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
 try
 {
 $res = $req.GetResponse()
 }
 catch [System.Net.WebException]
 {
 $res = $_.Exception.Response
 }
 $int = [int]$res.StatusCode
 echo $int
```

For Powershell 3.0:-

```
try{
$res = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseDefaultCredentials 
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
$res = $_.Exception.Response
}
$int = [int]$res.StatusCode 
echo $int
```

Both scripts are extremely doing well but if you want to find code status of many URLs, then you should go for powershell 3.0 , it handles web-requests in a much better way.